# Getting mean values from ANOVA in R

Tags: r, mean, anova

I'm using R to run `ANOVA` (the usual `aov()` code, which gives this information: `Df`, `Sum Sq`, `Mean Sq`, `F value`, `Pr(>F)`), and there is a piece of information that I haven't been able to get from these tables: Estimated marginal means for the dependent variable.

I know that it is possible to get this additional information from `ANOVA` in `SPSS`, but I haven't been able to replicate it in `R`.

A minimum of my data using `dput()`:

```
df<-data.frame(dep.variable = c(0.5092, 0.6965, 0.4308, 0.634, 0.4258, 0.3543, 0.6603, 0.5882, 0.3098, 0.5229), ind.v=c(3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L)
                  ,Control1=c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Control2=c(2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 4L))

   my_anova <- aov (dep.variable ~ ind.v*Control1*Control2, data = df)
```

My independent variable is a factor with `4` levels. I need the mean value of my dependent values for each level of the independent variable after controlling for `Control1` and `Control2`.

I'd appreciate your help on that.

Comment: could you please provide a minimum of your data using dput() , so that it would be easy to give an advise ?

Comment: @SALAR I just edited the post, hopefully the information is sufficient now.

Comment: Your update came just after I posted an answer! See if it helps as it is, otherwise I can edit it to use your MRE instead

Comment: I think you need to use the emmeans package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html where emmeans function is used the same as anova over the lm object.

Comment: Ok thanks and my last question is can you include your aov() formula? which categorical variable you want to get the marginal means?

Comment: @Coy Thank you for your response. It's definitely helpful, but since I also need to control for two variables, I'd really appreciate it if you could please use my MRE as I can interpret and replicate it better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SALAR I added my aov () formula and more explanation, please let me know if any additional info is needed.

Comment: @Naz I think this a bit too minimal an example (too many levels for such a small sample). It should be possible to compute at least a mean for each factor level (which is not possible for levels 1, 2 and 4 of your independent variable)

Comment: @Coy My actual sample size is 364, I just copied the first 5 as example. I know how to compute a mean value for each factor level. The issue is that I first need to control for two variables using ANOVA, and compute the new mean values after controlling for those two variables. That's what I don't know how to do. I'll be happy to add more example if that helps.

Comment: Your current data is too few to obtain the marginal means. Could you please provide more data? Before posting, make sure that you get no NaN in your ANOVA table with the minimum data.

Comment: @SALAR I doubled the example size, hope this is sufficient. There was also no NaN/error in aov table using the minimum data.

Answer (score 0):

`aov()` is a wrapper for `lm()`, tailored at providing the usual outputs expected for an analysis of variance. You can get the coefficients using `coef()` as with an `lm()` output, or just use `lm()` directly:

```r
x = data.frame(
  y = c(
    rnorm(10, 5, 2),
    rnorm(10, 8, 2)
  ),
  g = rep(letters[1:2], each = 10)
)

aov(y ~ g, data = x)
```

```
Call:
   aov(formula = y ~ g, data = x)

Terms:
                       g Residuals
Sum of Squares  33.06216  81.16610
Deg. of Freedom        1        18

Residual standard error: 2.123494
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

Use `coef()` to get the group means:

```r
aov(y ~ g, data = x) |> coef()
```

```
(Intercept)          gb 
   5.784686    2.571465
```

Or simply call `lm()`:

```r
lm(y ~ g, data = x)
```

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ g, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           gb  
      5.785        2.571
```

Note that the mean for the first group `'a'` is in the `(Intercept)` term, and the effect for `'b'` is the difference respect to this intercept. Actual group means would be the intercept for `'a'` and the sum of both coefficients for `'b'`.

For more than two factors the effects get confounded and there's no easy way to
get the group means from the model output (either `aov` or `lm`). The reason for
this, I suspect, is that these marginal means would only make sense if there's
no interaction between factors. There's a specialized package to handle this
called `emmeans`. I'll have to use a simulated dataset since the minimal example
still has too few observations for the number of levels:

```r
# sim parameters
n = 10
g_effects = c(
  'a' = 5,
  'b' = 8
)
ctrl_effects = c(
  'c' = 2,
  'd' = 4
)

effects = outer(g_effects, ctrl_effects, `+`)
effects
```

```
   c  d
a  7  9
b 10 12
```

```r
# generate data
X = data.frame(
  y = rep(effects, each = n) + rnorm(n * 4),
  g = rep(rownames(effects), each = n),
  ctrl = rep(colnames(effects), each = n * 2)
)

X
```

```
           y g ctrl
1   6.519858 a    c
2   6.704983 a    c
3   7.542411 a    c
4   3.915727 a    c
5   7.564559 a    c
6   7.840707 a    c
7   5.137290 a    c
8   7.696412 a    c
9   8.300361 a    c
10  5.942079 a    c
11  9.682047 b    c
12 10.551709 b    c
13  9.208265 b    c
14  9.249308 b    c
15  9.994033 b    c
16 10.969805 b    c
17 10.547202 b    c
18  8.613042 b    c
19 10.893566 b    c
20 10.513579 b    c
21  9.447953 a    d
22 10.432833 a    d
23 10.443755 a    d
24  8.896230 a    d
25  8.385421 a    d
26  8.250635 a    d
27  8.673966 a    d
28  9.684629 a    d
29 10.183822 a    d
30  8.721494 a    d
31 11.734383 b    d
32 10.844294 b    d
33 11.906789 b    d
34 11.890356 b    d
35 11.941118 b    d
36 11.708217 b    d
37 14.436147 b    d
38 12.601567 b    d
39 10.799885 b    d
40 14.598940 b    d
```

Now let's fit an ANOVA and take the marginal means:

```r
library('emmeans')

m = aov(y ~ g + ctrl, data = X)
emmeans(m, spec = 'g')
```

```
 g emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 a   8.01 0.247 37     7.51     8.51
 b  11.13 0.247 37    10.63    11.63

Results are averaged over the levels of: ctrl 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Answer (score 0):

So when looking at [this](https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/anova-in-r/) tutorial, it seems that R doesnt give you the mean values, like you would when looking at SPSS. Maybe you want to try a different library that gives you more info? You can also do it manually like in [this](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/anova-in-r/) tutorial. They simply get the mean for each group:

```r
PlantGrowth %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  get_summary_stats(weight, type = "mean_sd")
```

Please note that your categorical variables need to be binary to identify the effect of each category individually. (create dummy variables if need be)

Answer (score 0):

I generated a random dataset to increase the sample size as  an illustrative example of performing `ANCOVA` to generate estimable effects and means. Of course there are other assumptions that were not tested here (`checking model assumptions, choosing the best model, testing independence between covariates and factor variable`). For example, we need to verify that the covariates (`Control1,2`) and the treatment (`ind.v`) are independent of each other. Because including a covariate term into the model only makes sense if the covariate and the treatment effects are independent of each other on the response variable. Also, the other point is to decide which model would be the best model. Do we need to use a full model or drop some terms from the full model which they don’t make any sense by including them into the model. The other point is that, looking at the `?aov`, the function is appropriate when the data are balanced and the treatments have equal number of replicates. Otherwise functions e.g `lm()` would be more appropriate.  I assume the full dataset from the question owner is `balanced` so I would consider `aov()` for the `ANOVA` here. Also, I would like to show ANOVA base model (without covariates) and full model indicated by question owner to compare means estimated from the two models and comparisons between treatments.
Hope these could help.

```
set.seed(123)
x = rnorm(160)

# to generate data in ranges between 0-1.
min.x = min(x)
max.x = max(x)

dep.variable = (x - min.x)/(max.x - min.x)
ind.v = rep(1:4, each=40)
Control1=sample(1:2,size = 160,replace = T)
Control2=sample(1:7,size = 160,replace = T)

# make data frame
df<-data.frame(dep.variable,ind.v,Control1,Control2)

# convert ind.v to factor
df$ind.v <- factor(df$ind.v)

# center the covariates and save centered values in new columns
df$Ctrl1s<-scale(df$Control1, center = T, scale = F)
df$Ctrl2s<-scale(df$Control2, center = T, scale = F)

# run anova with and without covariates
aov.noCov <- aov (dep.variable ~ ind.v , data = df)
aov.Cov <- aov (dep.variable ~ ind.v*Ctrl1s*Ctrl2s, data = df)

#partitioning the sums of squares from the linear model using ANOVA here 
#We use type II sums of squares to address the presence of covariates

library(car)
Anova(aov.noCov, type="II") # anova for model without covariates
                  
Response: dep.variable
          Sum Sq  Df F value Pr(>F)
ind.v     0.0247   3   0.188 0.9045
Residuals 6.8224 156 

Anova(aov.Cov, type="II") # anova for model with covariates

Anova Table (Type II tests)
Response: dep.variable
                    Sum Sq  Df F value Pr(>F)
ind.v               0.0254   3  0.1850 0.9064
Ctrl1s              0.0275   1  0.5995 0.4400
Ctrl2s              0.0602   1  1.3138 0.2536
ind.v:Ctrl1s        0.0592   3  0.4302 0.7317
ind.v:Ctrl2s        0.0511   3  0.3714 0.7738
Ctrl1s:Ctrl2s       0.0014   1  0.0315 0.8594
ind.v:Ctrl1s:Ctrl2s 0.0095   3  0.0691 0.9763
Residuals           6.6005 144
```

to obtain the adjusted means with and without controlling for covariates, we use `lsmeans()` from package `lsmeans`.

```
library(lsmeans)
lsmc1<-lsmeans(aov.noCov, ~ ind.v) # get adjusted means with no covariate
lsmc2<-lsmeans(aov.Cov, ~ ind.v) # lsmeans controlling for covariates

lsmc1
ind.v lsmean     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 1      0.524 0.0331 156    0.458    0.589
 2      0.512 0.0331 156    0.447    0.577
 3      0.515 0.0331 156    0.450    0.581
 4      0.490 0.0331 156    0.425    0.555

lsmc2
 ind.v lsmean     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 1      0.512 0.0375 144    0.438    0.586
 2      0.513 0.0361 144    0.441    0.584
 3      0.503 0.0377 144    0.429    0.578
 4      0.492 0.0346 144    0.424    0.561
```

#The estimated means from the two models are not the same as we included covariates in the second model. Finally, we define the post hoc comparisons to make Pairwise comparisons. We use `Scheffé` or `Bonferroni` procedures here, as `Tukey’s` method is not appropriate for ANCOVA (`Kutner et al. 2005`).

```
summary(contrast(lsmc2, method="pairwise", adjust="Scheffe"),
        infer=c(T,T))
        
 contrast         estimate     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 ind.v1 - ind.v2 -0.000195 0.0521 144   -0.147    0.147  -0.004  1.0000
 ind.v1 - ind.v3  0.008977 0.0531 144   -0.141    0.159   0.169  0.9987
 ind.v1 - ind.v4  0.020152 0.0510 144   -0.124    0.164   0.395  0.9843
 ind.v2 - ind.v3  0.009172 0.0522 144   -0.139    0.157   0.176  0.9986
 ind.v2 - ind.v4  0.020347 0.0500 144   -0.121    0.162   0.407  0.9829
 ind.v3 - ind.v4  0.011175 0.0512 144   -0.134    0.156   0.218  0.9973
```

Here looking at the p.value we observe that none of pairwise comparison are significant as it is random dataset.
This is just try to show the steps for `ANCOVA` in the presence of covariates.